# VBA Code help to update date cell for each cell change

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to automate a date of response column in excel from various user. I had updated the code basis some R&D from various blogs, but is stuck on one place. My code is given below.
Same is able to record the date of change of a cell in next cell. And as I want only date of first update, it is doing fine. However, in case if user is removing the response, date is still there and thus ***"Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents"*** is not working.
Kindly help to update the code. My Requirement from the code as summarized as below:

1. It should update date of change of cell in next cell (Offset (0,1))
2. In case of multiple change of a cell, it only record first response date and should not overwrite previous date.
3. when a user delete the response, date should also be removed.

(Code will run in excel having approx. 2000 rows and approx. 10-20 of user will access the sheet.)

```
Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
On Error Resume Next
If (Target.Count = 1) Then
If Not Intersect(Target, Application.ActiveSheet.Range("U:U,W:W,Y:Y,AA:AA,AC:AC,AE:AE,AG:AG,AI:AI")) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each xCell In xRg
        If VBA.IsEmpty(xCell.Value) Then
            If Target.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1) = Now
            End If
            Else
            Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like a question to post on Stack Overflow...

Comment: code seems ok, unless you really meant to put the `End If` that is before the `Else`  to where the other `End If` is. This implies/results in a different logic.